# Odds of getting at least 50% correct answers

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

If I have four digits : xxxx that can take either 1 or 0. Then I have 16 permutations. (from binary 0000 to 1111). And when written down, we see that 11 of them have at least two 1's (68.75%), and 5 of them have at least three 0's (31.25%).

Suppose we have an exam where students should answer by "yes" or "no", and suppose that for a student to succeed he must answer correctly to at least 50% of the questions, and that students do not know the answers to the questions so they have to choose at random.

We know that in the case of one question the odds are 50%, for two questions the odds are 75%, for four questions (like the case of four digits) the odds are 68.75%.

How can we calculate the probability of getting at least 50% correct answers (1's) in case we have 100 questions for example? what equation to use in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $1$ be rewarded to every correct answer, $0$ for every wrong answer.

Then we need to find how many binary strings of $100$ numbers contain $50$ or more $1$'s.

---

For exactly $50$: There are $100$ slots for our numbers. Choose $50$ of them (the order you choose them does not matter), put $1's$ in them and $0's$ in the rest (there's only one way to do that, the order in which you put the ones into the chosen slots does not matter to us, similarly with the zeros as we will end up with the same exact  outcome).

There are ${100 \choose 50}(1)(1)={100 \choose 50}$ ways to do that.

For exactly $k$: There are $100$ slots for our numbers. Choose $k$ of them to put $1's$ and put $0's$ in the rest, again the order you chose slots does not matter as in the end we're going to put $1's$ in each one anyways and end with the same exact outcome.

There are ${100 \choose k}$ ways to do that.

We can have $50,51,....100$ ones, so we need to account for the number of ways we can get exactly each.

---

That number is $\sum_{k=50}^{100} {100 \choose k}$.

The total possibilities is $2^{100}$ because we either have a $0$ or a $1$ in each slot for two choices for every slot.

So the probability of getting at least half of the answers correct on a true/false test with exactly a hundred questions is,

$$P=\frac{\sum_{k=50}^{100} {100 \choose k}}{2^{100}}$$

$$=0.53979...$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious answer Ahmed, that was exactly what I was looking for, Best +1

Comment: Your welcome! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

For every case where a student answers the questions one way, there is an exact opposite case where as student answers every question the exact opposite way.  If the student answers exactly half correctly, the exact opposite will also have exactly half the answers correct.  Other wise one way will have more than half and the exact opposite will have less then half correct.

So the number of ways to get more than half correct-- is half of the number of ways to get more than half correct or less than half correct -- is one half of the total number of ways minus then number of ways to get exactly half correct.

The probability of at least half being correct is $\frac {\text{# more than half correct} + \text{# exactly half correct}}{\text{total # of ways}}=$

$\frac {\frac 12(\text{# total} - \text{# exactly half}) + \text{# exactly half}}{\text {# total}}=\frac 12\frac {\text{# total} + \text{# exactly half}}{\text {# total}}=$

$\frac 12 + \frac 12 P(\text {exactly half})$.

So if $n$ is odd then probability of at least half is exactly $1/2$ (which makes sense as either you have more than half or less than half and each equally likely.)

If $n = 2k$ then the number of ways to get exactly half is ${2k \choose k} = \frac {(2k)!}{k!k!}$.

So Probability of getting at least $k$ out of $2k$ questions right is $\frac 12 + \frac 12\frac {(2k)!}{k!k!2^{2k}}= 1/2 + \frac {n!}{(k!)^22^{n+1}}$

So $n = 2;k=1$, then $P = 1/2 + \frac {2!}{2^3} = 3/4$

If $n = 4; k=2$ then $P = 1/2 + \frac {4!}{2!2!2^5}= 1/2 + \frac {3}{16}=\frac{11}{16} = 68.75%$ etc.

If $n =100; k= 50$ then $P = \frac 12 + \frac{100!}{(50!)^22^{101}}=$

$\frac 12 + \frac{51*.....*100}{50!2^{101}}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this useful answer +1 :)